# NameError: name 'BillPayer' is not defined

Tags: python

I am getting the above error when trying to run my code. I believe it suffers from being a broad error, as all my googling has not brought me to anything that relates to my actual situation. I have organized the directory like this:

```
Project (BillPay)
    bill.py (contains Class Bill())
    billPayer.py (contains Class BillPayer())
    main.py
    __init__.py
```

I have left my `__init__.py` empty, which I understand to be ok.

In main.py, I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/home/matt/Documents/Code/BillPay")
import bill
import billPayer

bill_machine = BillPayer()
bill_machine.addBill(Google, 12345, 100.00, www.google.com)
bill_machine.printBills()
```

If I have imported the module billPayer (which contains the BillPayer class), then I should be able create an instance of that class, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Plain `import`ing only defines the module's name in the local namespace. You typically use it to qualify access the contents of the module, i.e. `bill_machine = billPayer.BillPayer()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two ways to go about it either

`billPayer.BillPayer()`

or

`from billPayer import BillPayer`

Answer (score 3):

```
bill_machine = billPayer.BillPayer()
```